# n-bit counter amortized analysis

Tags: algorithm, counter, amortized-analysis

Suppose we have a binary counter that supports two operations: incrementing and resetting all bits to zero. If the modification or examination of a single bit takes Theta(1) time, how can a counter be implemented as an array of bits so that any sequence of increment and reset operations on an initially zero counter takes O(n) time?

By aggregate analysis, and considering the fact that not all bits have to flip every time, I was able to see that a counter that just allows incrementing takes O(n) time for n operations. But I'm stuck on how to implement the increment-reset counter. As far as I can tell, a flip is a flip, and nothing will magically make 1111 become 0000 any faster than usual. I do notice, however, that with an increment operation, we won't get a super-expensive all-1s situation too often.

I guess the real question is, is there actually a *strategy* to realize an efficient counter with the reset utility, or am I merely trying to *prove* that it would turn out like a counter with just the increment operation? The only hint I have is to "keep a pointer to the high-order 1", which seems to suggest the former.

Comment: I think you're right about a flip being a flip. On the other hand, if you only reset the minimum number of bits, then you have to increment 2^i times before reset costs you i.

Comment: What do you mean by, "only reset the minimum number of bits"?

Comment: If you know where the highest-order 1 bit is, you don't have to reset any bits to the left of it. Otherwise, you'd have to reset all the bits to 0 everytime you did a reset, which is a lot costlier.

Comment: Ah. I guess I need to think more in terms of a real data structure and not just numbers on paper.